# "Три поросенка", но "Волк и семеро козлят" — почему в одном случае количественное, а в другом собирательное числительное?

Tags: числительные, количественно-именное-сочетание, собирательные-числительные

Почему "Три поросенка", но "Волк и семеро козлят"? Почему в одном случае количественное, а в другом собирательное числительное?

Answer (score 2):

Потому что в сказке говорится о козлятах не как об отдельно взятых,  а взятых в целом, как совокупность. В сказке " Три поросенка" каждый поросенок представлен как отдельно взятый, действующий персонаж.

Дополнение

Я задал этот вопрос Грамме.ру. И вот что они пишут: 
''Употребление собирательных числительных действительно ограниченно - не только грамматически, но и стилистически. Однако современные исследователи отмечают, что числительные этого разряда неуместны только в официально-деловом стиле речи и при обозначении существительными мужского рода престижных должностей, званий, чинов, профессии. При этом и в подобных сочетаниях указанные числительные возможны в контекстах констатирующего характера ("Сайт представляет пятерых поэтов начала века") и в непринужденной речи, когда говорящий непринужденно рассуждает о событиях собственной жизни ("Вчера были вызваны ко мне трое генералов"). Ибо их основное значение (обозначать количество предметов, животных, людей, которые представлены группой или действуют совместно, находятся вместе где-либо или переживают вместе какое-либо состояние) в таких случаях оказывается более существенным, нежели стилистическая окраска".

> На наш взгляд, Вы совершенно правы. Более того, в книге "Английские народные сказки" (серия "Сказки народов мира" изд-ва "Азбукварик", 2011) эта сказка дана в таком переводе: "Жила-была на свете свинья, и было у нее трое поросят".

Comment: Да, это разные поросята, каждый со своим характером.

Comment: Не понял юмора, или практика удаления это норма?  О чем собственно речь то идет? Эй там, на мостике, ау! Общественность в замешательстве...

Comment: Не ищите черную кошку...(и так далее). Просто так сложилось, хорошо звучит!

Answer (score 2):

три  -  three

трое - three

троица - Trinity

тройка - three

русская тройка - Russian threesome

триплет - triplet

трио - trio

трое в лодке не считая собаки - Three Men in a Boat (To Say Nothing of the Dog)

в принципе, у любого переводчика средств на русском достаточно, чтоб придать собственный смысл безликим английским типа three.

еще втроем -all three.

трешка и треха - непереводимое идиоматически дословно.

Answer (score 0):

> Почему "Три поросенка", но "Волк и
> семеро козлят"? Почему в одном случае
> Количественное, а в другом
> Собирательное?

Просто так получилось у авторов/переводчиков. Могло получиться и наоборот. По-русски ведь можно сказать  и  ***"Трое поросят", и "Волк и семь козлят"…***

Но это на мой взгляд...

Есть и другие мнения. Вот как обосновывает название "Три поросёнка" Ирина Борисовна Голуб:

> …Не случайно в переводе английской
> сказки написали «Три поросенка», а не
> «Трое поросят», ведь собирательные
> числительные имеют разговорную,
> фольклорную окраску, а эта сказка всё
> же не относится к русскому фольклору.

https://books.google.ru/books?id=ahEZAQAAIAAJ&q=%22%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%22&dq=%22%D0%A2%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8F%D1%82%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ei=q1zbVPXuDITIyAOW4IKgBQ&redir_esc=y

По-моему, Голуб не права.

Comment: Согласен с Вами, Слава.

Comment: Да, можно трактовать и наоборот. В первом примере всё воспринимается нейтрально (для невегетарианцев). Во втором - поросят очень жалко: они более одушевлены (возможно, эти трое были неразлучны, и каждый мог быть со своим характером).

Они съели три поросёнка (которых им продали поштучно). 
Они съели троих поросят.

Answer (score 0):

Вперёд выступило десять солдат - я указываю на группу из некоего количества.
Вперёд выступили десять солдат - я подчёркиваю, что из группы вышли десять человек, каждый  этим и отличен.

Answer (score 0):

По моему мнению, в данном случае был бы возможен и обратный вариант: трое поросят и семь козлят.
Сложилось так.